# Git clone on jenkins master, copy to slave

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I've set up a CI server running jenkins and a slave with a replica of our production environment. I'm running into a pesky little problem though: Jenkins apparently runs `git clone` on the slave which would mean that every slave should have it's publickey added to GitHub.

To me this sounds like a pretty weird architecture design. **I would prefer the master server (which has all my credentials) to `clone`/`checkout` and copy the workspace to the slave.** But after quite some Googling I haven't found a way to do this yet. I have found the [Copy to slave plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) but that doesn't prevent the slave from failing on a `git clone`.

I hope someone know a way to achieve this because setting up GitHub publickeys for every slave sounds ridiculous.

Comment: I'd say: Set up a local clone which sync regularly with github, let the slaves clone the local clone and build from there.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty complicated workaround for a simple issue. Right now I've setup GitHub hooks so builds are automatically triggered after a push. To me my question sounds like a pretty reasonable requirement, only have one server doing the SCM communication instead of all slaves. I'm hoping there's a more natural way to achieve this then setting up another clone and essentially losing a lot of the benefits from the Jenkins-Github integration.

Comment: Why can't you share one ssh private key among slave servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Jenkins apparently runs git clone on the slave which would mean that every slave should have it's publickey added to GitHub.

Why not use *one* **[deployment key](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys)** (for all Jenkins agent to use) for accessing your repo?

> A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on the server and grants access to a single repository on GitHub.
>   This key is attached directly to the repository instead of to a user account.
>
> ### Pros
>
> - Anyone with access to the server has access to deploy the repository
> - Users don't have to change their local SSH settings
>
> ### Cons
>
> - Deploy keys only grant access to a single repository, more complex projects may have many repositories to pull to the same server
> - The key has full read/write access to the repository
> - Deploy keys are usually not protected by a passphrase, making the key easily accessible if the server is compromised

---

The other approach is to use the [Credentials Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) (initialized in [February 2012](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/commit/a3b3ff0983693983b1736a0329136edee9095a10)), which allows to **store credentials in Jenkins master**.

> A single point for managing each credential. Change it in one place and you are done.
>
> As of version 1.5, the plugin now supports categorizing credentials into different "domains" in order to allow plugins to restrict the choice of credentials to only those that are appropriate.
>
> When a plugin is asking for a list of credentials, it can add some specifications about where and how the credential will be used.

Example of Credential Domain configuration:

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/59511751/Screen+Shot+2013-08-07+at+13.50.42.png?version=1&modificationDate=1375880556000]

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in recent Jenkins releases by centralizing credentials on master.

Comment: Which version does support it? How can I configure it?

Comment: What plugins do you use?